# Handlebars hide/show section depending on route url

Tags: routes, handlebars.js, hide, show

I'm using handlebars and nodejs to create a webpage with some sections (handlebars files) like: About us, Contact us, Our Services, Login, footer etc etc. By default all sections are visible but I would like to hide one of them if a call **Login Form**, setting url bar as: http://www.mypage.com/login. In my handlebars template I've got:
main.hbs

```
<body>
    {{> navbar}}
    <main class="container-fluid">
        {{> messages}}
        {{{body}}}
        {{> about}}
        {{> services}}
    </main>
    {{> footer}}
</body>
```

What can I do to hide or show {{> about}} or {{>services}} or whatever if I show up login form???. Login link is inside the navbar

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to use layouts (templates). Different handlebars files can use different layouts.

Have your main layout as normal.

The one you want to change, create a new layout, and when you call the login handlebars file, make it use a different layout.

I'm not sure how you set up your handlebars, but if its default, then your layout files is in views/layouts. In your layouts folder, create handlebars file and call it example main2.hbs, then below code is the route code that tells express to use layout main2 as the layout. Regarding your login form, I assumed you have a login page called login.hbs. If not, change 'login' to your handlebars view file.

```
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('login', {layout: 'main2'}) 
})
```

Comment: not what I'm expecting but definitely works for me, really easy way. Thank a lot, I own you one!

Comment: There are harder ways like if statements based on conditions and can use partials, but for your case its just layouts is the easiest. Keep it simple at the beginning, then make it more complex as your logic gets harder.